# Zeroclipboard.js is not working when I add jQuery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

My zeroclipboard.js is working nicely and easily copy the text to clipboard without  `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

But if I add the script to my website, it no longer works

Here is my demo coding:

[Without the script](http://bowser.effectgames.com/~jhuckaby/zeroclipboard/)

[With the script](http://www.immschool.com/test2)

Comment: _"How to resolve?"_ - Don't include the script that breaks it. Seriously though, do you get any error messages in the browser's JS console?

Comment: how to find any error messages in the browser's JS console?..I have a Firefox's firebug add-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's irrelevant. The problem here is not jQuery, but rather the fact that you forget to upload the `ZeroClipboard.swf` file to the server.

[image]

Either that, or you uploaded it to an unconventional path and you forget to set the `moviePath` on the ZeroClipboard object accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Now I have uploaded zeroclipboard.swf into my directory but still the error occurs dude..!

Comment: I see that you have your own `$` function defined in your code which is causing a conflict with jQuery. There are two options here. One, remove your own `$` function declaration and modify every argument passed into the function call to a CSS selector accordingly. Or two, call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: Sorry dude I don't have a such knowledge in jquery. So please provide the fully error free jquery coding for me..This part is very important for my project without this, my project is nothing..Thanks In Advance

Comment: Right after the jQuery `script` tag, call `$.noConflict()`.